# How to Make Gushup Web widget full screen and open by default

Tags: bots, chatbot, gupshup

I am working Gupshup Chat bot, 
I am trying to make Gushup bot full width i want the Chat bot to be full width and the Chat window to open by default when the chat window is loaded.
Please someone should tell show me how i can achieve this, am using the Gushup web widget on my website homepage but i need it to be full width to cover the whole of the page and also to be open by default. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

copy iframe html generated by chat popup using browser inspector